# What is the meaning of the single word "saying"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[News](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/i-dont-see-him-crying-uncle-trump-believes-china-tariffs-will-help-him-win-reelection/2019/05/14/e7fd67fe-7657-11e9-bd25-c989555e7766_story.html?noredirect=on)

> Trump cast the strength of the US economy as leverage, **saying**,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Saying*, on its own, would make little sense. But your quotation is incomplete.

From your link, this is the *actual* sentence—as well as the one that follows it for context:

> Trump cast the strength of the U.S. economy as leverage, saying, “We have all the advantage.” And he reiterated his threat to expand the tariffs to cover virtually all Chinese imports, saying, “We’re looking at it very strongly.”

---

You may have simply misinterpreted the comma after *saying* as being a period—when, in fact, it's a comma and the sentence doesn't end there.

Comment: Oh, My ... I used a software to split sentence and read them separately. I never thought it breaks at the wrong points. I have already closed this question.